# How to catch errors/exception in gekko when you have an infeasible solution?

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I am getting a `Exception: @error: Solution Not Found` with gekko. By using `disp=True`.
I got more details : `Unsuccessful with error code            0` and
`Warning: no more possible trial points and no integer solution Maximum iterations`. 
I was checking the documentation and there's no indication on how to know find out the type of the error. 
To summarize: I'm trying to catch the error type, so that I can handle it and return a proper response explanation for the error. 
Does anyone have an idea on how to find the type of the error ?

Answer (score 0):

The `m.options.APPSTATUS` returns a `0` (unsuccessful) or `1` (successful). Use `m.options.APPINFO` for the specific solver error code. Set `debug=0` to not return an `Exception` when the solver fails to find a solution.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

# Initialize model
m = GEKKO()

# Initialize variables
x = m.Var(value=1, lb=0, ub=1)
y = m.Var(value=2, lb=2, ub=3)

# Infeasible equation
m.Equation(x==y)

# Objective function
m.Minimize(x+y)

# Solve optimization problem
m.options.SOLVER=3
m.solve(disp=True,debug=0)

if m.options.APPSTATUS==1:
    print('Successful solution')
else:
    print('Application status: ',m.options.APPSTATUS)
    print('Error code: ',m.options.APPINFO)
```

This infeasible solution returns:

```
Application status:  0
Error code:  2
```

`Error code: 2` isn't very descriptive. Infeasible solution (2) or maximum iterations (1) are the most commonly encountered errors, so you could start with those. Here is a full list in the [IPOPT Documentation](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/OUTPUT.html). Other solvers such as APOPT `m.options.SOLVER=1` have different error codes. Here is a description of the [solver options](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver) in Gekko.

Comment: Thank you for your response John, I was wondering if maybe there's a way to get more details in the exception error message, which is not handled very well by Gekko. I know about APPINFO, but  I was looking in the docs for a meaning for all the error codes, I was getting a '-9' error code, and I couldn't find enough details about this particular code.

Comment: The error codes in `APPINFO` come from the solver, not from Gekko. I'd recommend looking at the solver documentation or set `disp=True` to see the corresponding error message.